# WPF modal window in Visual Studio Extension blocking input

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, modal-dialog, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

Using the following [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee943166.aspx), within a VSIX project, I created a WPF window that inherits from Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.DialogWindow, and I display this modally using the following code:

```
var myWindow = new MyWindow(myParameters);
myWindow.ShowDialog();
```

When I compile this in RELEASE mode and start without debugging [Ctrl+F5], it opens the Experimental version of Visual Studio.  Here, I open another Solution and then execute my Modal Window.  The window works just fine - I can type in text boxes etc, etc.

However, when I close the modal dialog window [using this.Close()], the problems start.  If I navigate to one of the documents in the open solution, I can type, but the keyboard buttons backspace [<-] and [Delete] (and possibly others too) are simply ignored....I can't delete what I've just typed!

Also, when I try to close this experimental version of Visual Studio, I get the following message:

> Microsoft Visual Studio has detected that an operation is blocking
>   user input.  This can be caused by an active modal dialog or a task
>   that needs to block user interaction.  Would you like to shut down
>   anyway?

But, as far as I can tell, my modal window has been closed and may even have been garbage collected by the time I get to close this instance of Visual Studio.

This isn't limited to the Experimental version - when I push this VSIX to our local gallery and install as an Extension, then I get the same behaviour.

I have also tried explicitly setting the owner, but his had no effect on this problem:

```
var myWindow = new MyWindow(myParameters)
{
    Owner = Application.Curent.MainWindow
}
myWindow.ShowDialog();
```

If I make this a non-modal window, then I get different (but related) problems.  Here, if I open the Experimental version of Visual Studio and open the other Solution where I navigate to a C# page.  I then open my Extension's WPF window where I can happily type into TextBoxes in that WPF window.  However, whenever I click the backspace [<-] or the [delete] keys, this doesn't affect the current WPF textbox but the previously opened C# code window in the current solution.  See [a previous post on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37996412/wpf-window-textbox-editing-text-affects-different-window)

What am I missing?

Comment: Note that the docs on `DialogWindow` say you should call `ShowModal` rather than `ShowDialog`. I don't know if that impacts your scenario or not, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following suggestion found [here](http://www.visualstudiogeeks.com/extensibility/visual%20studio/options-for-displaying-modal-dialogs-in-visual-studio-extensions) seems to work for me:

```
IVsUIShell uiShell = (IVsUIShell)ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(SVsUIShell));

uiShell.EnableModeless(0);

var myWindow = new MyWindow(myParameters)
{
    Owner = Application.Curent.MainWindow
}
myWindow.ShowDialog();

uiShell.EnableModeless(1);
```

Comment: I am glad to know you solved this problem and thanks for sharing the solution. Please mark it as answer, It will be very beneficial for other community members who have the similar questions.

Comment: You could simply make your window derive from DialogWindow (in PlatformUI).